# i want to get the div with the class name hour 0:00AM by the parent div day sun

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a weekly calendar and want to get the hour by the parent day (`sun`). I will do the same for for the other days and will get the classes from key/value array. I just want the simple js or jquery code to find it.

This worked for me, but it gets all `<div>`s under class `sun`:

```
$("div.sun >div.hour").addClass('selected');
```

```
<div class="day sun" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; background: transparent; width: 100%;">
    <div class="hour 0:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 1:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 2:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 3:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 4:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 5:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 6:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 7:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 8:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 9:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 10:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 11:00AM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 12:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 1:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 2:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 3:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 4:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 5:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 6:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 7:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 8:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 9:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 10:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 11:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
    <div class="hour 12:00PM" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221); margin-bottom: 1px; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `... with the class name hour 0:00AM` - These are two separate classes

Comment: Also, unrelated, but CSS uses the `:` character to denote pseudo-classes. While you could make the choice to escape it everywhere (e.g. `.7\:00PM { ... }`), I would *highly* advise you don't use `:` in class names. You'd be better off using a data attribute, ie `data-hour="7:00PM"`.

Comment: i know there's two classes as i told i will get the class name from loop in an aray so it will be hour 0:00am

Comment: @mohamedmohamed The attitude you show towards people that try to help you will not resolve in anything else than your question being voted to be deleted. People write comments mostly to help you, or help you improve your question. When TylerRoper ask hvad you have tried on your own, it's because it's a good idea to show people what you have tried, and what does not work.,

Comment: $("div.sun >div.hour").addClass('selected'); this worked for me but it gets all divs under class sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By combining two class selectors without a space between, ie `".class1.class2"`, you'll find elements that have *both* classes. However, the `:` will need to be escaped using `\\`.

```
var $7pm = $("div.sun >div.hour.7\\:00PM");
```

If you thought it neater, you could use an attribute selector instead:

```
var $7pm = $("[class='hour 7:00PM']");
```

That said, I'd suggest avoiding the hassle by using  `data` attributes:

```
var $7pm = $("[data-hour='7:00PM']");
```

```
<div class="hour" data-hour="7:00PM"></div>
```